# How can I contract 2 indices at my choice in a rank N tensor (ndarray)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2^L x 2^L matrix which is then converted to a tensor of rank 2L by reshape command with each axis having 2 elements. For example for L =2 it would be:

```
Z = np.asarray([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]) 
X = np.reshape(Z,[2,2,2,2])
```

I have tried to use `np.einsum` to sum, for example, L and 2L indices by swaping axes. But it would mess up the indices order so further contraction would be very difficult so I'm really struggling with how to perform such a contraction.

Comment: What exactly is your desired operation? Could you show for `L=1`? `[[1,2],[3,4]]->?`

Comment: What do you mean by `contraction`?  It's not a common term in `numpy`.   Are you trying to do addition along one of the axes?

Comment: Contraction means summing two axes in the ndarray. np.trace could do the trick as Paul said below

Answer (score 2):

### sum on one or more axis

Here's a wild guess as to what you mean by 'contraction' - `sum` along one or two axes.

```
In [239]: X.sum(1)
Out[239]: 
array([[[ 6,  8],
        [10, 12]],

       [[22, 24],
        [26, 28]]])
In [240]: np.einsum('ijkl->ikl',X)
Out[240]: 
array([[[ 6,  8],
        [10, 12]],

       [[22, 24],
        [26, 28]]])
In [241]: np.einsum('ijkl->il',X)
Out[241]: 
array([[16, 20],
       [48, 52]])
In [242]: X.sum((1,2))
Out[242]: 
array([[16, 20],
       [48, 52]])
In [243]: X.sum(2).sum(1)
Out[243]: 
array([[16, 20],
       [48, 52]])
```

### einsum trace

To explore `@Paul Panzer's` trace answer a bit more, a (0,3) trace can be calculated with `einsum` as:

```
In [314]: a1=np.einsum('ijki', a)   # repeated indicies
In [315]: a1
Out[315]: 
array([[ 9, 13],
       [17, 21]])
In [316]: a1[None,:,:,None]   # restore the dimensions
Out[316]: 
array([[[[ 9],
         [13]],

        [[17],
         [21]]]])
```

Doing this programatically from `i,j=0,3` takes a bit more work.  It's probably easiest to construct the alternative `einsum` syntax

```
a1=np.einsum(a, [0,1,2,0])

In [321]: dex=np.arange(a.ndim)
In [322]: dex[j]=dex[i]
In [323]: dex
Out[323]: array([0, 1, 2, 0])
In [324]: a1=np.einsum(a, dex.tolist())
In [325]: a1
Out[325]: 
array([[ 9, 13],
       [17, 21]])
```

The `newaxis` expansion can be built up from slices and `None`:

```
In [326]: dex=np.zeros(a.ndim, object)
In [327]: dex[...]=slice(None)
In [328]: dex[[i,j]] = None
In [329]: dex
Out[329]: array([None, slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None), None], dtype=object)
In [330]: a1[tuple(dex)]
Out[330]: 
array([[[[ 9],
         [13]],

        [[17],
         [21]]]])
```

But looking at how `expand_dims` works, the `reshape` route is easier:

```
In [334]: dex = np.array(a.shape)
In [335]: dex[[i,j]]=1
In [336]: dex
Out[336]: array([1, 2, 2, 1])
In [337]: a1.reshape(dex)
```

### Double contraction

You mentioned further contraction operations.  In this 4d case, I assume that means following up with a trace on axes (1,2)

```
In [426]: a2 = a1.reshape(dex)
In [427]: a2.shape
Out[427]: (1, 2, 2, 1)
In [429]: np.einsum('ijjk',a2)
Out[429]: array([[30]])
```

Both traces could be taken in one `einsum`:

```
In [430]: np.einsum('ijji',a)
Out[430]: 30
In [431]: np.trace(a1)
Out[431]: 30
```

### Timings

`einsum` tends to be as good as `dot`, though it looses out when the arrays get very big, and its iteration space grows.  But here it is consistently doing better than a double trace:

```
In [464]: N=100;abig=np.arange(N*N*N*N).reshape(N,N,N,N)
In [465]: abig.shape
Out[465]: (100, 100, 100, 100)
In [466]: timeit np.trace(np.trace(abig,0,0,3))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop
In [467]: timeit np.einsum('ijji',abig)
The slowest run took 7.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.2 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are referring to tensor contraction in the sense of "generalised trace", so let's see what `numpy.trace` can do for us:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)
>>> L, i, j = 2, 0, 1
>>> np.trace(a, axis1=i, axis2=L+j)
array([[ 9, 13],
       [17, 21]])
```

If you have to do that multiple times and don't want axes to shift, simply insert new axes to replace the contracted ones.

```
>>> np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(_, i), L+j)
array([[[[ 9],
         [13]],
        [[17],
         [21]]]])
```

In the very end you can `squeeze` the excess axes away.

```
>>> np.squeeze(_)
array([[ 9, 13],
       [17, 21]])
```

Comment: Thanks! The comment on excess axes is very helpful

Comment: For the (0,3) trace, `np.einsum('[ijki', a)` or `np.einsum(a, [0,1,2,0])` works

Comment: @hpaulj I really should learn that einsum magic! Does it have any advantages over dedicated functions where they exist? I think I read somewhere einsum used to be faster than numpy builtins. Is that still the case? Similarly, are there any reasons not to use `expand_dims` and other conveniences like `moveaxis`? They make life so much easier when axes and dimensions are not fixed.